# Detecting the rises in an array. (density of values)

Tags: c++, arrays, signals, blob

I am facing a challenge and wanted to ask for your suggestions.

I am coding in c/c++ and I have an array like below.

```
A[40]={0,0,1,0,2,7,18,45,80,85,88,91,88,65,12,3,0,1,0,2,1,2,5,45,88,89,78,79,65,12,5,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,1}
```

As you can see, there are 2 rises that we can also call them curves. 
This array stores the value of a real-time signal respect to the time.It works like a queue and refresh itself for every new value.

I want to detect and count the rises, I've tried some methods so far but couldn't figure out a  consistent solution yet.

My question is: how can I detect these curves and tell that there are 2 curves in array A?

Do you know any good way to detect them coherently? Or is there a method or something to handle this kind of signal works?

I really need the answer to advance on my project so all your answers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at something like an FFT. If the data is clean and simple you can just look for points of inflection (i.e. a sign change in the gradient).

Comment: you can do something simpler than FFT maybe - try a moving window to determine whether you are "rising" or "dropping", by comparing the last N values with the previous N values or something like that. as long as drops/rises are more or less one in one direction, you can pretty easily count them.

Comment: Another alternative is smoothing the curve and then looking for the local maxima. The smoothing will help avoid local maxima from showing as peaks.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Actually that is what I tried(using a window). I can compare the last and next n numbers to check it is rising or droping. for ex: if we suppose the array something like this: A=(5 8 18 16 25 38 40 35 21 11 4) in this case, this one also must be counted because it is also a curve that raises and drops. My algorithm fails here. I think there must be a way to make program to see the curves. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, maybe smooting works for the problem I mentioned in my comment above. But how to smooth? I know smooting on image processing but dont have any idea to perform it on a 1D array.Thanks.

Comment: @Horizon1710: Same difference... instead of performing the convolution with a bidimensional array you use a unidimensional array... Consider that it is a unidimensional image: for each position in the array sum the neighbors and divide by the number of neighbors. You can try with different window sizes and/or weights for each element. For example `[ 1 2 1 ] / 4.` will smooth but provide a higher weight for the center element (i.e. more chances of not *moving* the peak around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spot peaks in your data by looking for the points where the sign flips when comparing neighbouring values:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
  int diff(const int& a, const int& b) {
    if (b-a > 0) 
      return 1;
    else if (b-a < 0) 
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}

int main() {
  const int A[]={0,0,1,0,2,7,18,45,80,85,88,91,88,65,12,3,0,1,0,2,1,2,5,45,88,89,78,79,65,12,5,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,1};
  std::vector<int> delta;
  std::transform(A, A+((sizeof A/sizeof *A) - 1), A+1, std::back_inserter(delta), diff);
  for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = ++delta.begin(); it != delta.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it < 0 && *it != *(it - 1))
      std::cout << "Peak at: " << A[it-delta.begin()] << "\n";
  }
}
```

Note that you actually have more than two peaks in your data:

```
Peak at: 1
Peak at: 91
Peak at: 1
Peak at: 2
Peak at: 89
Peak at: 79
Peak at: 1
```

If they're not really peaks (just noise in the data) then you could fix that in a few of ways:

1. Quantization of the data.
2. Smoothing - i.e. alter each value to be more like its neighbours in some way.
3. Threshold. Record not just the sign, but the magnitude. Ignore changes smaller than a certain size.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your work, it is so clear. Actually the code piece you wrote above finds the values which are greater than its neighbours. So there can be many peaks eventhough curve number is 2. (I call it curve, I think you get what I want to mean, significant rise and its dropping). I'll try the 3. way, thresholding to ignore small drops while neighbours are rising. Thanks again.